# How does the compiler know not to optimize out reads on atomic_bool?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Assuming a thread running indefinitely until it's member variable stop is set. Like

```
while (!stop) {
  // do something
}
```

When stop is a simple boolean, the compiler can apparently do something like this

```
if (!stop) {
  while (true) {
  
  }
}
```

So even if another thread sets stop to true, it might have no effect at all.
But as far as I understood, using `std::atomic<bool>` does prevent the compiler from performing this optimization.

Question is: how?

Comment: You can look at how it's implemented in your standard library.

Comment: The "how" that happens is not specified in the C++ standard, it is left as an implementation detail.

Comment: Memory order constraints in addition to the atomic instructions. This is unlike `volatile` though which is only ordered relative to other `volatile`. Memory order constraints have "aquire", "release" or "both" semantics. The compiler can't pull ahead anything memory related in case of "aquire", and can't delay anything in case of "release". By default, it's "both".

Comment: [A good place to start](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/main/stl/inc/atomic)

Comment: Well, your premise isn't exactly correct. The compiler *can* optimize out the read of a non-atomic flag if it can prove that all possible writes to the flag that might occur from other threads will cause a data race. Otherwise (*e.g.*, mutexes are used to avoid data races in accesses to the flag), it can't do such optimization.

Comment: Similarly, if the compiler can prove that the *initial* load of the non-atomic flag also causes a data race, it's allowed to optimize out the loop entirely. Surrounding code can also be affected (the compiler is allowed to assume that the initial load will not be reached).

Comment: And how does it prove that? By assuming arbitrary memory access reordering unless something explicitly forbids reordering. The C++ memory model is completely unordered (even if x86 as an arch isn't, but that doesn't protect you!), as long as everything not explicitly ordered works correctly in a single thread each under "as if" rules. Thread synchronisation is all about global memory order,  simple as that. A mutex doesn't just yield, but the key feature is ordering.

Comment: @Ext3h so a memory order constraint in the loop would force the compiler to load the variable in every iteration? Would it matter whether it’s before or after the access in the loop?

Comment: The way it works is that `std::atomic<T>::load()` contains typically a low-level compiler-specific intrinsic function (eg. `__atomic_load_uint32(...)`). This function could be recognised by the compiler itself and may impact high-level optimizations (instruction reordering). In some compilers, the function typically contains assembly code with meta-informations about memory reads/writes/ordering and possibly allowed optimizations. For GCC, [see more information here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html).